# Rails 4 Ajax request with no authenticity token

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, authenticity-token

I am sending some very simple ajax post and patch requests via javascript in my application. The functionality is fine, works as intended. However, I do not see the authenticity token in the ajax request params and it still works.

## javascript (jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
  type:'PATCH', 
  url: '/dashboard/goals/#{@goal.id}.js', 
  data: $.param({ 
    new_invitation: { 
      recipient_id: recId, 
      type: "GoalInvite", 
      user_id : #{current_user.id}
    }
  })
});
```

and the params appear as follows in the log -

```
Parameters: {"new_invitation"=>{"recipient_id"=>"24", "type"=>"GoalInvite", "user_id"=>"23"}, "id"=>"234"}
```

no authenticity token. I think I know how I could add it in, but I am surprised that it even works without it. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `protect_from_forgery` in app. controller. ?

Comment: Yes it is in the app controller

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you inspect the request object you'll (hopefully) see that there's a request header named `HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN` that contains the authenticity token. The `jquery_ujs` library takes care of this for you so you dont have to include the token in AJAX requests manually.

Comment: yep the header was `X-CSRF-Token:`

Comment: It worked! after putting the line `= require jquery_ujs` in the `application.js` file. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that the jquery_ujs library does this for me. I was working on an external/client facing side of the app and didn't have this included, and couldn't figure out why only this particular ajax request was complaining about the auth token. Thanks!